# Error: unknown type name ‘pthread_attr_t’ in signal.h

Tags: c, emacs, cygwin, posix, newlib

I'm trying to build Emacs on Cygwin. Cygwin is the latest and fully patched. I use the platform as a test bed because of Newlib. Emacs is failing with:

```
gcc -DHAVE_CONFIG_H -I. -I../lib -I../src -I../src
-I/usr/local/include -DNDEBUG -pthread -D_XOPEN_SOURCE=600    -m64 -MT
close-stream.o -MD -MP -MF .deps/close-stream.Tpo -c -o close-stream.o
close-stream.c
In file included from /usr/include/sys/signal.h:22:0,
                 from /usr/include/signal.h:6,
                 from ./signal.h:52,
                 from ./sys/select.h:107,
                 from /usr/include/sys/time.h:47,
                 from ./sys/time.h:39,
                 from ./sys/select.h:86,
                 from /usr/include/sys/types.h:68,
                 from ./sys/types.h:28,
                 from ./fcntl.h:50,
                 from binary-io.h:23,
                 from binary-io.c:3:
/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h:175:3: error: unknown type name ‘pthread_attr_t’
   pthread_attr_t *sigev_notify_attributes; /* notification attributes */
   ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Examining `/usr/include/cygwin/signal.h` around 175, I see:

```
typedef struct sigevent
{
  sigval_t sigev_value;                 /* signal value */
  int sigev_signo;                      /* signal number */
  int sigev_notify;                     /* notification type */
  void (*sigev_notify_function) (sigval_t); /* notification function */
  pthread_attr_t *sigev_notify_attributes; /* notification attributes */
} sigevent_t;
```

But I don't see an include for the pthread gear in the `signal.h` header file. I believe the header should be either `<sys/types.h>` or `<pthread.h>`.

If I am parsing Open Group's [2.2.1 POSIX.1 Symbols](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/xsh_chap02_02.html)
and [Define _POSIX_SOURCE in cygwin's features.h?](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2006-01/msg00642.html) correctly, it should be sufficient to define `_XOPEN_SOURCE` to `600`. From the section *"The _XOPEN_SOURCE Feature Test Macro"* in the Open Group docs:

> Since this volume of IEEE Std 1003.1-2001 is aligned with the ISO C
>   standard, and since all functionality enabled by _POSIX_C_SOURCE set
>   equal to 200112L is enabled by _XOPEN_SOURCE set equal to 600, there
>   should be no need to define _POSIX_C_SOURCE if _XOPEN_SOURCE is so
>   defined. Therefore, if _XOPEN_SOURCE is set equal to 600 and
>   _POSIX_C_SOURCE is set equal to 200112L, the behavior is the same as
>   if only _XOPEN_SOURCE is defined and set equal to 600...

I found one past message that's similar at [Errors when compiling gnutls-3.3.17 with gcc-5.4.0](https://cygwin.com/ml/cygwin/2016-06/msg00458.html), but its reported as an upstream bug and it appears its fixed. I don't think it applies here since the pthread data structure is used without an apparent declaration or definition.

Can anyone confirm things are (not?) working as expected? If things
are working as expected, then hints to work around the failure would
be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,